# c++: good name for argument argument conversion classes

Tags: c++, type-conversion, parameter-passing

In C++, I sometimes end up with utility classes like this:

```
struct time_ref
{
   time_ref(FILETIME & ft) : ftval(&ft), ttval(0) {}
   time_ref(time_t & tt) : ttval(&tt), ftval(0) {}

   FILETIME * ftval; 
   time_t   * ttval;
}
```

They rely on implcit conversions e.g. to reduce the numner of overloads:

```
void Foo(int x, int y, time_ref t)
```

Rationale: if `Foo` has another parameter with overloads, the prototypes multiply, e.g. 3 overloads for X * 2 overloads for t is 6 prototypes, compared to 3 with above converter (or even one if two converters are used).

---

They always:

- have implicit constructors for two or mroe types
- should be used only as function parameters to enable these conversions

Thye differ in:

- Number of types supported
- can store a value, or a reference
- how the callee detects what type was provided (in the case above, it's the non-null pointer. Another typical implementation is an enum field and a union of data values)

---

**Questions:**

**1. Is there an accepted / common name for this pattern?**  I usually call them "argument converter" or "argument adapter", which doesn't seem common

**2. any recommendaitons to formalize them**  - e.g. is there a way (apart from adding a comment saying so) to ensure they are used only as parameters? Any other things to be aware of?

Comment: I guess the logic for dealing with each argument is somewhat separate, so you don't actually need (arg 1 type count) * (arg 2 type count) * (arg 3 type count) different implementations?  In that case, you could probably use templates to get back to (arg 1 type count) + (arg 2 type count) + (arg 3 type count) overloads.

Comment: @sbi: that's what I typically use when there are two types, I have a use case with 5 ;)  - I was wondering if the *pattern* has a common name

Comment: @peterchen: But all those five types must have something in common, or you wouldn't put them together, right? Why not name the struct after that? In the above case, `time` seems to be as good a name as you might get it. (I don't think there's a pattern for what you're doing, and even if there were one described somewhere, the answers show it would be too unknown to be any help for those coming after you.)

Comment: The struct name is `time_ref` - because it holds a reference to a time (details  here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/timeconvert2.aspx)  ---- yeah, it seems it doesn't have a common name. I'll continue to be undecided between "argument adapter" and "parameter covnerter". ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shim is often a good choice when you need to handle many different argument types, even after your interface is "done".  It allows you to do the conversion in a modular, fairly reusable way. See [this wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_Tunnel_pattern) and its referenced articles for more information.

Comment: Seems there is no common name for the pattern. I accepted this answer because it provides an alternate implementation (even with a name)

Answer (score 1):

1. As you are probably aware, in C++ "accepted/common" depends on the platform you're running on. A Unix C++ program defers in conventions from a WIN32 C++ program, for example. That said, I haven't seen these kinds of classes very often, for obvious reasons: they incur a performance overhead. You are creating a new object on every call to the function, which is rather unnecessary. It does save you some code, though, so it may be worth it in specific cases, but still it should be carefully considered.
2. As far as I know there is no way in C++ to restrict a class t be used only as a parameter. At least they cannot be instantiated without receiving one of the supported types in their constructors. One thing I'm thinking about is that you should probably support a copy ctor to allow passing the converter class itself between calls (if you have two separate function sets like you described, and one calls the other).

Comment: Thanks. I consider this not platform specific (in the Win32 vs. Unix sense) - the types are, the pattern is portable in C++.

Comment: Yes, definitely, the pattern itself will work. I was referring the naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with overloads ? It's perfectly safe to define Foo(X) that is implemented using Foo(Bar(X)). I think it's clearer that crafting wrapper classes.

Comment: See rationale: imagien a method that takes three Win32 resource ID's that can be either ints or strings: wihtout adapter, that's 8 overloads right there. If you add a 3rd way of identifying a resource, you have 27 overloads. `Foo(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_TB1), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1), _T("quickhelp_1"))` is IMO not clearer than `Foo(IDR_TB1, IDR_MENU1, _T("quickhelp_1"))`.